# htaccess http to https for domain and domain/paths

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, https

I need to convert all http access to a domain including its potential pages under the main page, to its https equivalent. What I have now just directs all Domain and www.Domain access to https://Domain but not pages that are off the main page. How can I modify the htaccess commands so in addition I can get http://Domain/other-web-pages to go to https://Domain/other-web-pages

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close. The redirection works, but you need to actually hand over the requested path too:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L,R=301]
```

Such general should get implemented in the actual http server's central host configuration. If you have no access to that you can use a *distributed* configuration file instaed. Such file has to be placed inside the http server's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

Comment: I am afraid that this ended up responding with: Error 500 - Internal Server Error
An error was encountered while processing your request. Typically this is a temporary condition. Please contact the web site owner for further assistance. - For both http://Domain as well as for http://Domain/page-path. I can see the requested URL was  https://Domain yet this error appeared in lieu of bringing up the page. I fell back to the prior htaccess file. Is there a way to log what the ReWriteRule actually is writing to be able to view for format before it is executed?

Comment: @JayMosk Check for subtle typos in your implementation. This looks OK to me. It is the same as your initial code except for the last line. (If you still have issues then check your server's error log for the details of the 500 error.)

Answer (score 0):

<sup>(An alternative to [@arkascha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74803881/369434), that builds on your existing code.)</sup>

> ```
> :
> RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com [L,R=301]
> ```

You are already capturing the requested URL-path (ie. `(.*)`) but not passing this through to the *substitution* string. So, all you need is the corresponding backreference (`$1`) that contains the URL-path. For example:

```
:
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

And, if you have other directives, this needs to go near the top of the `.htaccess` file before any existing rewrites.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing, since any erroneous 301 (*permanent*) redirects to the homepage will have been cached by the browser. Test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid such caching issues.

Comment: I am surprised that you apparently prefer capturing the path to reuse it ... Could you please elaborate why that is? Always curious to learn ...

Comment: This set of htaccess commands did in fact correctly handle all the variants of converting http requests to https requests.

Comment: @arkascha I don't necessarily "prefer" it, but since the OP is already "capturing the path" in their existing code, simply adding the backreference to the substitution string would seem to be the obvious "correction" and the smallest change necessary to make this work. (A learning exercise.)

Comment: @Jay Please consider upvoting answers that you find helpful and "accepting" answers that work for you. This not only shows your appreciation for the help given, but also helps other readers in determining the correct solutions. Thanks, much appreciated. :)